# Реализовать функцию на scheme(racket), которая возвращает все возможные подмножества заданного множества

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

Возникла проблема создания функции на языке scheme, которая возвращает все возможные подножества заданного множества, включая нулевое множество.
На вход функция принимает список, например:

```
(sets-of-set '(a b))
```

И возвращает `nil`, т.е. пустое множество:

```
(nil (a) (b) (a b))
```

Пытался найти решение на просторах интернета, но это закончилось неудачей. Также смотрел пару учебников:

> The Scheme Programming Language
>
> Structure and Interpretation  of Computer Programs

В них тоже ответа не нашел.

Как мне реализовать эту функцию? Или лучше всего, как должен выглядить конечный код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет, не совсем Scheme но идея думаю ясна.

```
ELISP> (defun combos (list)
  (if (null list) '(nil)
      (let* ((a (car list))
             (d (cdr list))
             (s (combos d))
             (v (mapcar (lambda (x) (cons a x)) s)))
        (append s v))))
combos

ELISP> (combos '(a b c))
(nil
 (c)
 (b)
 (b c)
 (a)
 (a c)
 (a b)
 (a b c))
```